# Let $G$ be a group of order 315 with a normal 3-Sylow subgroup. Prove $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

I know this it a prevalent question, I really do. It's just that every proof requires using Automorphisms groups about which we were barely taught. I can't start learning everything about Automorphisms by myself (Nor can I tell how far to learn about it) for I don't know how necessary it is if we weren't taught about it. I would appreciate that if you could help me circumvent those proofs that use the autumorphisms. Thank you.

Comment: Let $P$ be the normal Sylow $3$-subgroup. Use Sylow's Theorem to show that the inverse images in $G$ of the Sylow subgroups of $G/P$ are abelian, and then use Sylow's Theorem in $G$ to conclude that all Sylow subgroups are normal, and hence $G$ is abelian.

Comment: That's a direction, I shall try, thank you :)

Comment: Why does the fact that all sylow subgroup are normal mean the G is abelian?

Comment: [it](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324886/on-groups-of-order-315-with-a-unique-sylow-3-subgroup?rq=1) can maybe be of any help.

Comment: They all use AutG. 
I wonder if people read what I wrote...

Comment: @Meitar, that is not *only* what that comment is saying, but the fact that they all are normal **plus** abelian (direct product of abelian groups with coprime orders...?)

Comment: I am assuming you know that all groups of order $9$ are abelian. A direct product of abelian groups is abelian. There is no use of automorphisms at all in this argument.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{P\}=Syl_3(G)$. Since $|P|=9=3^2$ (the square of a prime), $P$ must be abelian. Hints:

(1) Study the *N/C Theorem*. Observe that $P \subseteq C_G(P) \subseteq G=N_G(P)$. Hence $G/C_G(P)$ embeds homomorphically into $Aut(P)$.
(2) Note that $Aut(P) \cong C_6$ or $\cong GL(2,3)$. Hence $|Aut(P)|$ divides $6$ or $48$, so $|G/C_G(P)|$ divides these numbers, as well as $5 \cdot 7$.
(3) Conclude that $G=C_G(P)$, that is $P \subseteq Z(G)$, the center of $G$.
(4) Use the fact that there is only one group of order $5 \cdot 7$, and that has to be $\cong C_{35}$.
(5) Use the general fact that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ must be abelian.

Comment: It uses AutP and more which I have a hard time understanding :( But thank you for your attempts.

Comment: But this uses automorphism groups, and the request was for a proof that does not.

Comment: (and @Derek) Yes, you are totally right, but I still encourage you to study that within the realm of the N/C theorem. At the same time let me rethink a proof without automorphisms.

Comment: Why is that $|G/CG(P)|$ needs to divide $5∗7$?I was thinking that $|G/CG(P)|$ needs to divide $5∗7$? I was thinking that $|G/C_G(P)|$ should divide $3^2 * 5 * 7 $, could you help me out with this doubt? Thanks!

Comment: $315=|G:C_G(P)|\cdot|C_G(P):P|\cdot|P|=|G:C_G(P)|\cdot|C_G(P):P|\cdot 9$, so $35=|G:C_G(P)|\cdot|C_G(P):P|$.

Answer (score 2):

OK, without automorphisms: put $\{P\}=Syl_3(G)$, $Q \in Syl_5(G)$ and $R \in Syl_7(G)$. Observe that $G/P \cong C_{35}$ (I leave it to you to prove this with again Sylow Theory). Hence $QP \unlhd G$, since $QP/P \in Syl_5(G/P)$. Further it is easy to see that $Q$ is the only Sylow $5$-subgroup of $QP$. Hence $Q \text{ char } QP \unlhd G$, so $Q$ is normal in $G$. Same reasoning applies to $R$. Then $G=PQR$, three normal subgroups that mutually intersect trivially, since their orders are relatively prime. Hence $G \equiv P \times Q \times R$ and is abelian.

Comment: @Timbuc, ah corrected typo, it should have been $P$. Thanks!

Comment: How exactly did you infer that $Q$ normal in $G$ ?

Comment: @Daniel: if a Sylow subgroup $S$ of a group $X$ is normal, then it is even *characteristic*, that is, it is invariant under any automorphism of the group $X$. In our case $Q$ is characteristic in $QP$. But $QP$ is in its turn normal in $G$. It is straightforward to show that in general $A \text { char } B \unlhd C$, implies $A \unlhd C$ (sketch of proof: conjugation with elements of $C$ induces an automorphism of $B$ and leaves $A$ invariant).

Comment: New useful facts to my arsenal, thank you !