# Prove: A group of order 315 with a normal 3-Sylow group is Abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Prove: A group of order 315 with a normal 3-Sylow group is Abelian.
I know that $315 = 3^2\times5\times7$ I've tried using Sylow's theorems on 5, 7 but haven't got anywhere meaningful. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: there is answers here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324886/on-groups-of-order-315-with-a-unique-sylow-3-subgroup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be such a group. Let $P_k$ be Sylow k-subgroup for $3,5,7$ of $G$, respectively. First, $P_3$ is a normal abelian subgroup. Then $P_3P_5$ and $P_3 P_7$ are subgroups of $G$ since $P_3$ is normal. Furthermore, they are abelian subgroups by the Sylow theorem. We may conclude that the centralizer $C_G(P_3)$ of $P_3$ has oreder at least $3^2\cdot 5 \cdot 7$. Thus $C_G(P_3) = G$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Which theorem were you using to say that there are Abelian? Also how did you conclude that the centralizer has such an order?

Comment: To see that the subgroup $K:=P_3P_5$ is abelian. First, by the Sylow theorem, $P_5$ is normal in $K$ since $K$ has order $3^2\cdot 5$. Since $P_3 \cap P_5 =\{e\}$, we may conclude that elements of $P_3$, $P_5$ commute. Similarly, $P_3P_7$ is also abelian. 

To see that $C_G(P_3)=G$. Note that the order $|C_G(P_3)|$ is divided by $3^2$ since $C_G(P_3) \supseteq P_3$ (recall that a group of power $p^2$ with prime $p$ is abelian). And $C_G(P_3) \supseteq P_3P_5$ so  $|C_G(P_3)|$ is divided by $5$. Similarly,  $|C_G(P_3)|$ is divided by $7$ since $C_G(P_3) \supseteq P_3P_7$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped!

Comment: @Khako You've shown that $|C_G(P_3)| = 315$, so $P_3$ is contained in the center. Why must $G$ be abelian?

Comment: $C_G(P_3)$ is a subgroup of $G$ and its order is at least 315, so it has to be equal to the group itself. Also, we know that $C_G(P_3)$ is abelian and so has to be the group $G$ (because they're equal)